# Spliting Front-end from Back-office on Maven

Tags: spring, maven-2, module, spring-roo

I've a java ecommerce web-based app.
It is written using Spring Roo, so it follows the Domain Driven Design paradigm.
The application has two UI.
The first is front-end, based on plain jsp/jstl/tiles, it is stable, changes rarely and HAVE to STAY UP and RUNNING.
The second is built on Vaadin/GWT, it changes frequently (on Custemer requerements).

My question is how to best structure Maven project such as:

- Allow deploy (on tomcat) only back-office or front-end UI;
- Do not duplicate Domain Logic

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the domain objects out into a different library from the gui code.

Then have 2 seperate wars both depending on this library.

This is a very standard pattern.

Comment: OK, in that case they are two completely different applications as I required.
But is there a way to build them also as one app? merging in some way at least the web.xml for servlet mapping?

Comment: Many ways - you could put them both in a ear. Or you could overlay one war with the other. To decide on the best one for you I'd need to know why you want to do this. Maybe ask another question.