# do not understand how to architecture my GWT based application for back-end website

Tags: html, gwt, frontend, backend

I need a website well referenced on the web (SEO), and also accessible without JS. But I also need an administration for this website (I do not want to use a CMS for my case), so I want to do my admin application in GWT (I do not have experience in GWT). In order to help me, I wiil use the Spring Framework.

What I do not understand is how things happen at the level server (I have never developped a JAVA APPLET)...Do I have just one project (Spring) that will receive/send http requests for my website **and** that will also let people using the GWT app ?

Will non-js browser be always able to go to my website (**I am afraid that the GWT app will imply that my website will also nedd js**) ?

Sorry if I am not clear, maybe you can understand my problem and recommend me something ?
Tkx,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, GWT heavily uses JavaScript, so if this is a requirement for you: rather have a look for another framework like Spring for instance. Probably have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=java+web+framework which brings up tens of questions regarding this topic.

Furthermore, don't mix Applets with server-side application, those are purely client-side applications (and rarely used nowadays).

Comment: Ok, so how is the way I do in order to use, from one part SPRING + GWT for my admin part and pure html for the website (my website does not need MVD isn't it?) ?

Comment: Yes, this sounds reasonable. You could also use Spring to generate the HTML for your webpage. Just GWT is not suitable for your requirements.

Comment: I understand, but, maybe I do not have the good vision of the architecture...my problem looks like this one : [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5661916/spliting-front-end-from-back-office-on-maven) and it let me hope that there is a solution. I summarize my problem : "with one domain name, I want 2 thinks : one app (pure JS, so done with GWT) and one website". Moreover the same database will be used for the two 'front end'. Can you understand more exactly my situation now (so is it possible and is it a good architecture design ?)

Comment: Sure you can do this. We are also using parts of the same backend logic (EJB etc) and use it in different contexts. Since the GWT server side can (and in the standard case - GWT RPC - is) a servlet, you can run those in, e.g., Glassfish or JBoss and use for instance the database access in both parts of your application.

Comment: Ok, but I have understood (recently), that if I use SPRING framework so I will not have an EJB architecture...so what is the equivalent of EJB in Spring ?

Comment: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/ejb.html ... Plus EJB was just an example. You can of course also use Spring POJO injection or anything else.